# jQuery codes pushing elements all at once in one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to push one image, name, username, tweets on the a div box content one at a time. However, what my code does is that it push everything in on div box content as seen here:

[image]

I used a while loop and then create divs from it and push the elements (name, username etc) from each div class box-content.

Here's my codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  generateFeed();
});

function generateFeed(){
  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while(index >= 0){
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var $tweet = $('div#main-content');
    var mybox = $tweet.append('<div class="box-content"></div>');
    $('<img src="" align="left" class="avatar-main">').appendTo('.box-content');
    $('<h5 class="fullNameMain"> <span class="userNameMain"> <span class="timePosted"></span> </span></h5>').appendTo('.box-content');
    $('<p class="tweetContent"></p>').appendTo('.box-content');
    $('<ul class="activities">' +
      '<li><span class="comment"></span> 48K</li>' +
      '<li><span class="retweet"></span> 50K</li>' +
      '<li><span class="heart"></span> 100K</li>' +
      '<li><span class="msg"></span> 22K</li>' +
      '</ul>').appendTo('.box-content');
    mybox.find('.avatar-main').attr('src', 'img/' + tweet.user + '.png');
    mybox.find('.fullNameMain').prepend(tweet.user);
    mybox.find('span.userNameMain').prepend('@' + tweet.user);
    var d = new Date();
    if(d.getSeconds() >= 59){
       mybox.find('span.timePosted').text(' * ' + d.getMinutes() + 's ago');
    }else if(d.getSeconds() < 59){
      mybox.find('span.timePosted').text(' * ' + d.getMinutes() + 'm ago');
    }else if(d.getMinutes() < 59){
      mybox.find('span.timePosted').text(' * ' + d.getHours() + 'h ago');
    }

    mybox.find('.tweetContent').text(tweet.message);
    index -= 1;
  }
}
```

Any idea how to put fix this and pull the elements (name, username, etc) one by one and put them on the div class box-content? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you don't want it to do all of them?

Comment: fyi, your the contents are actually being insert one by one, just that the speed is too fast you cant see it. Try using `setInterval`.

Comment: @YongQuan Browsers don't render anything until the script finishes and returns to the event loop. So everything done by a script is done at once.

Comment: @Barmar: trying to create the loop for each div. How do I fix it?

Comment: Use a timer to create just one DIV. Or create all the DIVs at once, but hide them and show just one at a time with a timer.

Comment: @DJTam where is `streams.home.` declared/defined?

Comment: @Barmar: can we move this to chat so we can talk to it deeply? I would appreciate if we could.

Comment: Sorry, I have to go. But there are many examples in SO and in tutorials.

Comment: What is the data structure of index?

Comment: add `console.log(streams.home)` at first line of function `generateFeed` amd show console iutput